# Image upload to tinymce for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce, image-uploading

I know this questions have been asked before, but I'm still searching for a free and easy-to-use image uploader for tinymce compatible with MVC 4. Most examples are a bit old and not working too well. I think there should be an awesome new one out there somewhere :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone is interested I ended up writing my own plugin with a little help from http://justboil.me/ and using the fine uploader.

Comment: I am interested and would LOVE to see your plugin for it.

Comment: Hi, i'm also very interested in this one

Comment: @hammerpath can you please upload your code ? so we can apply for same in our tiny mce ?

Comment: The question explicitly asked for asp.net mvc but the justboil.me site says it has a PHP requirement. Can you please elaborate on how it will work with asp.net?

Comment: Did you ever link to your code? I think it would very helpful to show a more complete answer of uploading images with ASP.Net and TinyMCE. I'll gladly post it as a question, if need be. Or maybe you could just edit your answer and include some code. I would appreciate any help!